# Deleting owners of a security group from organization

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-groups, security-group

I couldn't find the documentation on if we (an admin) can delete the owners of a security group and if we can, what happens if we did delete them from the organization (either through AAD or Microsoft 365 Admin Center). I would really appreciate your help, if you happen to know.

Thanks!

Edited: Here "Deleting" means deleting/removing the user from the organization due to being retired or laid off or left the company.

Answer (score 2):

An **Office 365 group** is a **Security Group** within Azure Active Directory.

Groups have their own permission model that comprises the roles Owner and Member.

- **Owners**: manage the group (e.g. changing titles, managing members and privacy settings)
- **Members**: collaborate around content (e.g. conversations in Yammer and Outlook, documents within a SharePoint team site)

If the admin deletes the owner of the Security Group, this user no longer has **Full permission** of this site collection and **cannot access the site collection**. Unless the admin grants access permission to the user later.

[image]

[image]

——————————————————**Updated Answer**————————————————

Delete user from **Office 365 Group**(Security Group) **owners**.

[image]

This user no longer has **Full permission** of this site collection and **cannot access the site collection**.

---

**Office 365 Groups are a new breed of security groups**. It is not just a security group, but a security group with “benefits.”

You can read more about an Office 365 Group [here](https://sharepointmaven.com/office-365-groups-or-sharepoint-team-sites/).

---

Comment: Appreciate your reply. sorry I wasn't clear. By deleting a user, I mean a user being deleted or removed from the organization/tenant. And it is strictly about the security group because Microsoft 365 groups can be created by non-admin users whereas security groups can be created only by Admins.

Comment: Hi, Aks. I have updated the answer, hope this helps you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi, EchoDu_MSFT. Thanks for you reply. And very sorry for delayed reply. Been away due to Covid.
If I may pick your brain some more - Imagine there is a security group (not an office group even though they are a better version of security groups) which has owner X and member Y. Now, the time passes, the user Y and X both leave the company for better opportunity. So, after everything is done, these two accounts are of no use to company, the admin removes/deletes them from the AAD (not from group). What happens to the group now? Does it become orphan? Does any admin automatically become owner?